# Internet access through wireguard over multiple hops

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables, wireguard

I am trying to achieve the following:
**I want my personal computer `A` to connect to the internet through a raspberry pi `C` on a wireguard VPN.**

Most guides on the topic assume the internet gateway is a direct peer, but this is not the case here. This is because `A` and `C` are both behind a NAT and they connect to a VPS `B` to establish a wireguard connection.
Hence, my target "architecture" looks like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> Internet
```

Also, I want only A to access the internet through C, not B.
I call this wireguard network "`bvpn`".

I have been following this answer https://serverfault.com/a/1081164 and do have a working connection like the one I described.
However, it is extremely slow and when I run `mtr` or `ping` I get very high packet loss (over 70%).
Also, I experience a high CPU load (100%) on `A` when executing a ping to e.g. `8.8.8.8` by a `kworker/event` thread.

To find the source of the problem, I set up another wireguard network called "`wg1`" between `A`, `B` and `C`, but without setting up internet access for `A` through `C`.
In this network, no issues occur when connecting to `B` or `C` from `A`.

Furthermore, there are no internet access or ping problems when performing the requests/ping directly on `C`.

**Do you know why I experience these packet loss / connection problems in the `bvpn` network?**
I posted the exact wireguard configurations below:

**`bvpn` network**:

Wireguard config on `B`:

```
# This is host B
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.2.1/24,fd7e:07f3:d15b:ed77::1/64
SaveConfig = false
ListenPort = 51822
PrivateKey = <secret>
Table = bvpn
 
PreUp = echo 123 bvpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
PreUp = ip rule add iif %i table bvpn
 
PreUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
PreUp = ip6tables -A FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
 
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
 
PostDown = ip rule | grep "from all iif %i" | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -L1 ip rule del prio
PostDown = sed -i '/bvpn/d' /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
 
# Host A
[Peer]
PublicKey = eNa8aK6Y4laktZ0JeaWEs50oUmPXfW+hHorZiIlQ5yA=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.2.2/32,fd7e:07f3:d15b:ed77::2/128
 
# Host C
[Peer]
PublicKey = nisqd5xrYSmKl07XeocGY/UlM2dzOTYBPP29hBkrW10=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
```

(https://pastebin.com/mgCcwzs4)

Wireguard config on `C`:

```
# This is bvpn config on host C
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.2.3/24,fd7e:07f3:d15b:ed77::3/64
SaveConfig = false
PrivateKey = <secret>
 
PreUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
PreUp = ip6tables -A FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT

PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fd7e:07f3:d15b:ed77::0/64 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s fd7e:07f3:d15b:ed77::0/64 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
 
# Host B
[Peer]
PublicKey = /dANIceGpP1nMOTDToVgmX5yLTxLJt6/djxfUFPY9F8=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.2.0/24,fd7e:07f3:d15b:ed77::/64
Endpoint = <secret>:51822
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

(https://pastebin.com/jcQLqNqr)

Networkmanager config on `A`:

```
[connection]
id=BVPN
uuid=64bda4ef-ea45-49a7-b5c0-caa1f8147c7b
type=wireguard
autoconnect=false
interface-name=bvpn
permissions=
timestamp=1646086134

[wireguard]
mtu=1300
private-key=<secret>

[wireguard-peer./dANIceGpP1nMOTDToVgmX5yLTxLJt6/djxfUFPY9F8=]
endpoint=<secret>:51822
persistent-keepalive=25
allowed-ips=0.0.0.0/0;::/0;

[ipv4]
address1=10.0.2.2/32,10.0.2.1
dns=1.1.1.1;
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
address1=fd7e:7f3:d15b:ed77::2/128,fd7e:7f3:d15b:ed77::1
dns=2606:4700:4700::64;
dns-search=
method=manual

[proxy]
```

(https://pastebin.com/c97h0wpe)

**`wg1` network**:

Wireguard config on `B`:

```
# This is host B, wg1 network
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.1.1/24
SaveConfig = false
ListenPort = 51821
PrivateKey = <secret>

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT

# Host A
[Peer]
PublicKey = eNa8aK6Y4laktZ0JeaWEs50oUmPXfW+hHorZiIlQ5yA=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.2/32

# Host B
[Peer]
PublicKey = nisqd5xrYSmKl07XeocGY/UlM2dzOTYBPP29hBkrW10=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.3/32
```

(https://pastebin.com/M9Db7Yhh)

Wireguard config on `C`:

```
# wg1 config on host C
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.1.3/24
SaveConfig = false
PrivateKey = <secret>

# Host B
[Peer]
PublicKey = /dANIceGpP1nMOTDToVgmX5yLTxLJt6/djxfUFPY9F8=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.0/24
Endpoint = <secret>:51821
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

(https://pastebin.com/tCSi6e5S)

Networkmanager config on `A`:

```
[connection]
id=WG1
uuid=bcdeb01f-6592-4bf7-98ea-19ea41030ea6
type=wireguard
interface-name=wg1
permissions=
timestamp=1644622378
 
[wireguard]
mtu=1300
private-key=<secret>
 
# Host B
[wireguard-peer./dANIceGpP1nMOTDToVgmX5yLTxLJt6/djxfUFPY9F8=]
endpoint=<secret>:51821
persistent-keepalive=25
allowed-ips=10.0.1.0/24;
 
[ipv4]
address1=10.0.1.2/32,10.0.1.1
dns-search=
method=manual
 
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=ignore
 
[proxy]
```

(https://pastebin.com/vhvbBp1V)

Comment: Try using the same MTU value (eg 1300) on each hop.